# MySQL InnoDB FKID constraint fails?

Tags: mysql, constraints

```
ALTER TABLE 
  history
ADD CONSTRAINT 
  FKID_workorder 
FOREIGN KEY 
  (id_workorder) 
REFERENCES 
  workorder (id_primary)
```

What could possibly cause this constraint to fail? workorder has a 1:m relationship with which is what I think might be causing the problems but why? I created the constraint on the history table to imply that 1:m relationship...

What am I missing or doing wrong?

EDIT | Error

**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aerospace_erp`., CONSTRAINT `FKID_workorder` FOREIGN KEY (`id_workorder`) REFERENCES `erp_workorder` (`id_primary`))**

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry I guess that would help :p

Comment: Two things to look out for: data type of both fields must match exactly; all records in the referring table must have a reference in the referred table.

Comment: id_workorder and id_primary are identical types only id_primary is auto-incrementing -- not sure I get that last comment?? workorder is the referenced table history is the referring table. history can have ZERO or more records that associate with workorder and this constraint won't allow that???

Comment: You misunderstand. If you're applying a foreign key constraint your tables must meet that before the constraint can be applied. i.e. every history row must relate to a work order or, every row in `history` (the referring table) must have a corresponding record in `work_order` (the referred table). Many history rows can relate to one work_order row. If a work_order doesn't have a history, that's fine.